# Não entendi essa forma de declaração de variável estática

Tags: java, declaração-de-variável

Por que esta declaração não parece método em nem atributo?

```
static{

}
```

esse é o código original

```
private static MessageDigest md5 = null;

        static {
            try {
                md5 = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

O prof. não soube explicar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essa declaração é usada dentro de uma classe quando queremos executar algum trecho de código na inicialização da classe, o que inclui atribuir alguma coisa para uma variável `static`.